# Problema con el cursor en la terminal abierta desde neovim

Tags: cmd, terminal, vim, nvim, neovim

**Estoy usando neovim en windowns 10.**

Mi problema es que cuando abro la terminal en `nvim` con el comando `:terminal`, se abre la terminal y puedo mover el cursor con los comandos `h` `j` `k` `l` ; pero una ves que entro en modo inserción en la terminal, ya no me deja moverme a otro `buffer`.

muestro el antes:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

muestro después de entrar en modo inserción `i` :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver en la imagen, intento moverme al `buffer` izquierdo y no resulta; y aunque presione `Esc` no volverá al modo normal. la única forma que vuelva al modo normal es dándole clic(mi complemento) al buffer del terminal. Esto me corta mucho cuando programo; no se si existe algún comando que permita salir del modo inserción en la terminal.

gracias por leerme...